# restoring mysql database from mysqldump file

Tags: mysql

I had a mysql database on my windows machine and I wanted to move it to my mac. I took a mysqldump on windows into a .sql file and now I'm trying to restore from this file. But I get this error:

> ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: '??-'.

After going through this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44721/error-while-restoring-a-database-from-an-sql-dump I ran file utility on this file on my mac and it gave me this: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode English text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators. How do I restore from this backup file? Is the format of the file wrong?